# How to mark the simple_form checkbox based on a Array object?

Tags: checkbox, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

The Rails view has two parameters

```
list_of_attributes = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]
user_selections = ["a2", "a4"]
```

I am able to display the appropriate checkboxes and any associated user selections using the following simple_form definition

```
<% list_of_attributes.each do |item| %>
   <label>
     <%= check_box_tag "user_selections[]", item, user_selections.include?(item) %>
     <%= item %>
   </label>
<% end %>
```

How can I define the above behavior using simple_form f.input syntax? With the following definition, I am able to display the appropriate checkboxes, but any user selections is not 'checked'.

```
<%= f.input key, as: :check_boxes, collection: list_of_attributes, 
 :label => key, class: "form-control" %>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This worked for me using bootstrap CSS. Check line 25 in my github repo [here](https://github.com/mayordwells/alpha-blog/blob/master/app/views/articles/_form.html.erb)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">
            <%= f.collection_check_boxes :your_model_ids, Your_model.all, :id, :list_of_attributes do |cb| %>
            <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text} %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And then use this in your CSS file for the custom input_checkbox class above

```
    .input_checkbox input {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding checked attribute got the f.input definition functional.

```
<%= f.input key, as: :check_boxes, 
                    collection: list_of_attributes,
                    :label => key, 
                    checked: user_selections,
                    class: "form-control" %>                                    
              <% end %>
```